# cross-fetch doesn't work with React Native

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, fetch-api

I've written an API wrapper that uses fetch for execution of the API requests. As I intend the module to be compatible with Browsers, Node and React Native, I use [cross-fetch](https://github.com/lquixada/cross-fetch). Now, if I test it with Node it works perfectly, but if I use the wrapper in React Native if fails with the following error: `TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'cross_fetch_1.default(url, init)')`. If I print the type of cross_fetch_1 I get:

```
{ [Function]
  polyfill: true,
  Response: { [Function: Response] error: [Function], redirect: [Function] },
  Request: [Function: Request],
  Headers: [Function: Headers] }
```

and "undefined" for either cross_fetch_1.default or cross_fetch_1.fetch.

The library was developed in Typescript, so the cross_fetch_1 variable is created by the TS compiler. You can find the Typescript code here https://github.com/tgamauf/onetimesecret-api/blob/1b8edff66bde11807c8ff7d29030b4d3e6661277/lib/request.ts#L150 and the compiled JS here https://github.com/tgamauf/onetimesecret-api/blob/1b8edff66bde11807c8ff7d29030b4d3e6661277/lib/request.js#L179.

As far as I can tell I am using the module as it is supposed to be used. What could cause this?

I've also opened a github issue about this here: https://github.com/lquixada/cross-fetch/issues/26

Comment: If you're going to submit a Stack Overflow question and an issue report concurrently about the same issue, please link each to the other to help prevent duplicate work.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I have added the link to the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import `cross-fetch` in React Native, the React Native module bundler selects `node_modules/cross-fetch/dist/browser-ponyfill.js` according to the `browser` field of `node_modules/cross-fetch/package.json`; I believe this is configured [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/7a69f1aa272a9b71755033a80f6f4aa5e9dcbaf6/local-cli/util/Config.js#L70).  And `node_modules/cross-fetch/dist/browser-ponyfill.js` provides only an export assignment, not a default export:

```
if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
module.exports = fetch;
}
```

Contrast with `node_modules/cross-fetch/dist/node-ponyfill.js`, which has both an export assignment and a default export:

```
module.exports = exports = fetch;
exports.fetch = fetch;
exports.Headers = nodeFetch.Headers;
exports.Request = nodeFetch.Request;
exports.Response = nodeFetch.Response;

// Needed for TypeScript.
exports.default = fetch;
```

Enabling the `esModuleInterop` compiler option on your project will make TypeScript patch over the difference and fulfill your default import using the export assignment.  However, since `node-ponyfill.js` clearly suggests that the `cross-fetch` authors intended to support consumers that use TypeScript without `esModuleInterop`, I'd say they should fix `browser-ponyfill.js` to work in the same scenario.  I see you have already filed [an issue](https://github.com/lquixada/cross-fetch/issues/26).

Comment: Activating `esModuleInterop` solved my problem. Thank you, Matt!